# Jacoco code coverage reports not generating for integration tests, not showing in sonar

Tags: maven, jacoco

I had configured Jacoco + Sonar in Maven. I am able to generate the coverage reports for unit tests & display the coverage in Sonar as well. But, unable to generate the reports for integration tests. "jacoco-it.exec" is generated but, when I go and open the index.html, it looks empty. But, there are many integration tests got executed & passed as well. In jacoco-sessions.html, it is clearly mentioned about all the classes which are used internally. Please help me if you have any idea what is wrong in the below code wrt integration tests. I have configured Sonar also properly & given the path to pick up the results for integrations tests. Please see once and help me if you have any idea.                                        pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>  
 </configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
 <id>pre-integration-test</id 
<phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
<goals>
<goal>prepare-agent</goal>
</goals> </execution>
 <execution>
<id>post-integration-test</id>
<phase>post-integration-test</phase>
<goals>
<goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>                                                                                                                                                                                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                    <includes>
                        ....<There are integration tests>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        ....
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal> 
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions> 
            </plugin>
```

Comment: How did you solve this? My sonar with Jacoco is not showing coverage for Kotlin integrated tests however working for other Kotlin and java test cases